# Specs for repository/software function

Tags: github, cocoapods, specs

Specs for repository/software.

I saw many repository on Github or other place the repository have a `Specs` incidental project for it.

A few examples:

1. [nova-specs](https://github.com/openstack/nova-specs) for
   [nova](https://github.com/openstack/nova)
2. [neutron-specs](https://github.com/openstack/neutron-specs) for [neutron](https://github.com/openstack/neutron)
3. [Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) for [CococaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods)

Before ask this question, I have queried many data on internet.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spec#English) give a very brief introduction, not can explain the `Specs` for a repository.

in the internet there is no explain the Specs for a repo's detail explanation.

I also tried to understand the specs, only get the specifications word for it, does it just write for user to understand the repo? just like a instruction book?

If the function is only the upper, how about the Specs's specifications, is it self-defined? I saw the [Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) there are three level `1,2,3,4,5,....d,e,f` 16 directories in the directory framework. and the CocoaPods-Specs also have other functions, such as install configuration.

---

**EDIT**

My question is simple:

1. Whats the Specs project for a repo in Github functions?
2. Is the Specs project have specified role ? How to understand the [Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs)'s directories about the `0, 1, 2, 3, ...d, e, f` directories in it?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For CocoaPods, the Specs directory is the shared location for all publicly shared podspec files. More details [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html).

The subdirectories are used to manage the number of files in the repo so that there wouldn't be a huge number of files in one directory. The b/0/7 is generated from a hashing scheme of the podspec name.